# проблема работы с kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

[image: скриншот проблемы]
я не понимаю что не так, устанавливю по инструкции на оф сайте, переустановил и питон и пэйчарм и киви, весь день на это потратил, еще вчера все работало, помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не называй свои файлы именами модулей! В данном случае у тебя в проекте есть файл с именем `kivy.py`

Comment: Оу, без задней мысли так назвал, вообще крайне логично, стыдно что сам сразу не додумался, спасибо